# html2canvas resources loading in every loop iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html2canvas, jszip

I'm trying to capture multiple images using `html2canvas` and zip them using `JSZip`

currently I'm using JQuery array of promises to accomplish this like this:
 *(code details are not very important for answering, only to give you insight of my solution)*

```js
$scope.loopCanvas = function (zip) {
    var deferreds = [];
    var zip = new JSZip();
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfInnerDivs; i++) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferreds.push(deferred.promise());
        $scope.generateCanvas(i, zip, deferred);
    }

     $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function () {
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
            .then(function (content) {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                blobLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(content);
                link.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
                    link.href = blobLink;
                    link.download = 'page' + ($scope.currentPage + 1) + '-date' + $scope.dateSearch + '.zip';
                }, false);
                link.click();
                magnaMainService.LoadingIcon.hide();
            });
    });
}

function generateCanvas(i, zip, deferred){

    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#card-" + $scope.object.id)).then(canvas => {
        zip.file($scope.object[i].name + ".png", canvas.toDataURL().substr(canvas.toDataURL().indexOf(',') + 1), { base64: true });
        deferred.resolve();
    });
}
```

Everything works fine, but each iteration `html2canvas` is loading fonts, css files, and images again and again, which some of them even aren't needed.

I have 20 images to loop through and **(each iteration loads 400KB) * (20 iteration)**.

**Question:**
Is there a way to generate all separated images in one `html2canvas` iteration, or make it load styles only once, or somehow load less data?